# ImageMagick remove background noise and leave it white

Tags: imagemagick, ocr

In order to be better prepared for the OCR process, I want to remove the background noise on my images.

Right now I play with `-lat` parameter of ImageMagick tool:

```
magick.exe image_02_RESIZED.jpg -lat 20x20+10% test.jpg
```

but it completely removes the background from the image.

This is the sample output of the mentioned command:

[image]

Instead of this - I need to have the white background with a black text on it. How to do this with ImageMagick for Windows?

Comment: Add `-negate` to invert it, maybe? Otherwise you appear to have given us the result of a command that doesn't work so we don't have much to work with really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the color you want to replace with `-opaque` and the new color with `-fill`.

```
magick image_02_RESIZED.jpg -fill white -opaque black test.jpg
```

Here is the result of this command:

[image]

You can also add a tolerance with `-fuzz` to remove noise around text; here is a sample command with tolerance set to 5%

```
magick image_02_RESIZED.jpg -fuzz 5% -fill white -opaque black test_05.jpg
```

This is the result of the command with `-fuzz 5%`:

[image]

You can experiment a bit to find the optimal value for `-fuzz`